# How to insert values into table once

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I run my code or add new date to database my values get added again to tables. I don't know if it is an issue with how I create table or add values.

my code:

```
$uzk_len="create table if not exists buyers
        (
             id int(4) primary key auto_increment,
             code varchar(4),
             name varchar(30),
             adress varchar(30)
        )";
$uzk_lenv=mysql_query($uzk_len) or die ("table not created");
$uzk_duom="insert into buyers
         (code,name,adress)
         values
         ('1001','Maxima','Tilzes 25'),
         ('1002','IKI','Tilzes 111'),
         ('1003','Rimi','Saules 58'),
         ('1004','Norfa','Pramones 195')";
$uzk_duomv=mysql_query($uzk_duom) or die ("Failed to insert");
```

Comment: `Drop` the table before re-creating it. That `if not exists buyers` stops the create from running if table already exists

Comment: 2. Stop using `mysql_*` functions are depreciated and removed. use either `mysqli_*` or `pdo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the table before creating new.
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS buyers;`